# How do I sum and group by across multiple identical tables in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Due to a brain freeze, I'm having trouble writing the following SQL query.  Let's say I have user purchases stored in identical tables like `purchases1`, `purchases2`, `purchases3`.

Each purchases table has these fields: integer `id`, integer `user_id`, numeric `amount`.  Each user can have multiple purchases in multiple tables.

I want to get "total purchase amounts" for all users, in one query.  If I was selecting from a single purchases table, I would do:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) FROM purchases1 GROUP BY user_id;
```

I know I can `UNION` three queries like this to end up with three sums for each user and then add those in a parent query to end up with the total.  But that doesn't seem like the "right" way and gets especially messy if I have even more purchase tables.  It seems like it should be possible to aggregate across the three tables as if they were one continuous table.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"UNION three queries like this to end up with three sums for each user and then add those in a parent query to end up with the total."* <--- yes that is the correct way. The reason you are struggling and this feels uglier then it ought to, is because your data schema is terrible. There should only be one `purchases` table and whatever the `1`, `2`, and `3` mean on `purchases1`, `purchases2`, and `purchases3` should be its own column in that one table. In short, your feelings were spot on. Correct your schema before this gets unbearably ugly and slow.

Comment: @JNevill, thanks for the suggestion.  Multiple tables are for archival purposes: imagine every year, the current table becomes "last year's table" and a new one is started.  Can't redo the schema to use partitioning because there are way too many constraints and this is an actively used db.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case then a big UNION will be needed. If you are going to be doing this often, then you may want to make a view that has the UNION in it to save you some typing, but that won't help with the speed issue you will likely run into as the years go on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
WITH combined_purchases AS (
SELECT user_id, amount FROM purchases1
UNION
SELECT user_id, amount FROM purchases2
UNION
SELECT user_id, amount FROM purchases3)

SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) FROM combined_purchases GROUP BY user_id;
```

`UNION` all the data and then perform the same aggregation.